# JSF can't get a renderer for a custom composite input component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm building my custom JSF composite component in order to input periodicities. I've got this model:

```
public class Periodicity implements Serializable {

    private PeriodicityType type;

    private Integer value = 0;

    public PeriodicityExchange() {
        super();
    }

    /**Getter and setters**/

}
```

Where `PeriodicityType` is an enum containing `DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH`, `YEAR`.

The input component for this model consists of a [`p:spinner`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/spinner.xhtml) element to select a numeric value and a `h:selectOneMenu` to select the periodicity type. The component works well, but now I want to have a java class backing it, so I have modified my facelet file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<composite:interface componentType="periodicityInput">
    <composite:attribute name="value" type="model.Periodicity" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <p:spinner binding="#{cc.periodicityValue}"
            value="#{cc.attrs.value.value}" min="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <h:selectOneMenu binding="#{cc.periodicityType}"
            value="#{cc.attrs.value.type}" styleClass="form-control">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="No periodicity" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Days" itemValue="DAY" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Weeks" itemValue="WEEK" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Months" itemValue="MONTH" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Years" itemValue="YEAR" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

And that's my java class (based in [this BalusC's tutorial](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html)). It's registered as a component using the faces-config.xml file:

```
public class PeriodicityInput extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    private UIInput periodicityValue;

    private UIInput periodicityType;

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object newSubmittedValue)
            throws ConverterException {
        try {
            return new PeriodicityExchange(
                    Integer.parseInt(newSubmittedValue.toString().split("-")[0]),
                    newSubmittedValue.toString().split("-")[1]);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ConverterException(ex);
        }
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }

    public UIInput getPeriodicityType() {
        return periodicityType;
    }

    public UIInput getPeriodicityValue() {
        return periodicityValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSubmittedValue() {
        return periodicityValue.getSubmittedValue() + "-" + periodicityType.getSubmittedValue();
    }

    public void setPeriodicityType(UIInput periodicityType) {
        this.periodicityType = periodicityType;
    }

    public void setPeriodicityValue(UIInput periodicityValue) {
        this.periodicityValue = periodicityValue;
    }

}
```

The issue is that as soon as I use the `componentType` attribute to bind my component to the java class, the component stops rendering. `encodeBegin` gets called, but doing some further debugging, I've noticed that when JSF tries to get the renderer for the composite component, it returns null. The method `getRenderer(FacesContext)` from the `UIComponentBase` class tries to access `context.getRenderKit().getRenderer(getFamily(), rendererType)`, where the family evaluates to `javax.faces.Input` and `rendererType` to `javax.faces.Composite`.

I'm using Mojarra 2.2.12. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *where the family evaluates to `javax.faces.Input`*

This is not correct. It's supposed to be `javax.faces.NamingContainer`, the constant value of [`UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html#COMPONENT_FAMILY).

The `COMPONENT_FAMILY` below is likely messed up during refactoring with static imports:

```
@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return COMPONENT_FAMILY;
}
```

The above is actually inherited from `UIInput` while it has to be `UINamingContainer`. Better specify it with FQN.

```
@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a catch!! Thanks, Balus, it would be good to have it specified in your tutorial for hopeless copy-pasters like me xD. By the way, is it possible to return a null value in `getSubmittedValue`? I would be interested in the whole periodicity object to be null when no periodicity type is selected, but I guess it might conflict with the validation phase. If you want I could post a new entire question for that or edit this one.

Comment: You're welcome. As to the spinoff question, do the null-conversion job in `getConvertedValue()`.